# Are there any issues of have huge files in HD in a 32 bit system?

Tags: linux, windows, memory, filesystems

I know that in 32 bit systems the largest memory we can have is 4GB (2^32). But I am not clear what is the implication of this in terms of files.
I think that we can have files of arbitrary size in our HDs right? A lot more than 4GB. So are there any caveats in 32 bit systems and large files?
I assume that certain 32-bit programs would not be able to load files of more than 4GB or am I wrong?

Comment: programs don't read the file at once into the memory, this is done in chunks, so you can still open and play the file.

Answer (score 7):

It only matters if you have an application that tries to load the entire file in memory.
A programmer that does that for such large files should be shot. There are better ways.

Some software might burp on very large files (large meaning > 2 Gigabyte), but such software will usually do that on 64-bit systems too.
In most cases it is due to the programmer having the software designed for and tested with smaller files. The software contains logic errors preventing it working properly with very large files. It is not a limitation of the OS itself.
(Very common example is using a signed 32 number to keep track of the position in the file, which gives issues at the 2 GB boundary.)

In case of your example video: Only a small part (the part that is actually playing and a number of additional seconds of buffering) is typically loaded in memory. Usually not more than 2-3 Megabytes at a time.

As for arbitrary size files on a harddisk: That is not true.
Every filesystem has limits on the maximum size of any single file.
E.g in case of Fat32 that limit is 4 GB per file. NTFS has a limit of 16 TB. The Linux filesystem ext3 has a 16GB, 256GB or 2TB limit depending on whether the filesystem uses 1K, 2K or 4K blocks.

Comment: `16GB, 256GB or 2TB limit depending on whether the filesystem uses 1K, 2K or 4K blocks` How does the size of the block affect the limit of the files?

Comment: @Jim The ext3 filesystem manages files in units of blocks. The limit is thus determined by how many block a file can have. This you then have to multiply by the number of bytes in a block to get the maximum filesize. This is not unusual. Almost every filesystem internally deals in blocks and derives its upper limits from how many blocks per file it can manage. Some filesystems set the real limit lower than the theoretical max. This can be for performance reasons or commercial (you have to buy a more expensive license if you need very large file support).

Answer (score 4):

> I know that in 32 bit systems the largest memory we can have is 4GB (2^32).

This is wrong; it is perfectly possible for a 32-bit CPU to use more than 4 GiB RAM, just like it's possible for a 16-bit CPU to use more than 64 KiB RAM. Recall that [the 16-bit 80286 could address 16 MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80286#Architecture) through its 24-bit address bus (at the time this was considered a huge amount of memory; the 80286 became available in 1982, and [1983 saw the introduction of the first 3.5" hard disk, sporting a 10 MB *storage* capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_hard_disk_drives#Timeline); the [IBM PC AT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_AT), which was designed around the Intel 80286, came with a minimum of 256 KiB of RAM), and the 1979-vintage [Intel 8086 had an address space of 1 MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Segmentation) (and provided the computational capacity of the [original IBM 5150 PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer) which could be upgraded to the same 256 KiB amount of RAM, well beyond the native limit of a 16-bit address of 64 KiB). Look up techniques such as [Physical Address Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), [bank switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_switching) (which, though requiring care on the part of the programmer, was common in early PCs and earlier electronic computers due to its relative implementation simplicity; [the Apollo Guidance Computer was a bank-switched design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer#Memory)) and segmented memory models such as the [x86 memory segmentation model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation).

The ultimately limiting factor for how much memory can be addressed without relying on such techniques is the width of the CPU's native [address bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_bus), which is independent from [the CPU's native word width, or bitness as normally referred to](https://superuser.com/q/191762/53590). It would be perfectly possible to make a CPU that works with data in 64-bit chunks (which would make it a 64-bit CPU) even though it has a 16-bit address bus; I can't see any real application for something like that, but it isn't technically a contradiction.

Now, lots of people don't bother with these techniques on 32-bit CPUs because around the time that they were common in PCs, 4 GiB was really all you needed, and 32-bit CPUs generally had wide enough address buses to not make this a concern; even the reduced-capability [80386SX had a 24-bit usable address bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386#The_i386SX_variant), allowing for 16 MiB of address space in 1988 when the same year saw the introduction of [a 20 MB hard disk setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_hard_disk_drives#Timeline). Not needing to concern yourself with segmentation, PAE and similar techniques makes life *a lot* easier on the programmer. 32-bit server software, however, was commonly written to handle more than 4 GiB of RAM.

And of course, for perspective, 16-bit software regularly worked with files larger than 65,536 bytes. It takes a little thinking if you want your software to natively work with files that are too large to fit into a singly-allocated block of memory, but it definitely isn't impossible.

> But I am not clear what is the implication of this in terms of files. I think that we can have files of arbitrary size in our HDs right? A lot more than 4GB.

No, you cannot have *arbitrarily* large files, even if constrained by available physical storage space: at the lowest logical level, the file system puts limits on how large files can be stored, simply because it needs to be able to store the size of the file somewhere. The exact limit varies with the file system and sometimes with settings. With modern file systems such as NTFS, ext4, and so on, the limits are high enough that you are unlikely to hit them with a single disk, although it *may* be a concern if you have a large storage array. For example, *NTFS* (the file system) supports file sizes of up to 16 EiB, although the *NTFS implementation* in Windows is currently (artificially) [limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Limitations) to a maximum file size of just under 256 TiB (raised from 16 TiB by the release of Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012).

16 TiB is not an excessively large amount of storage; you can get there by running e.g. 7 disks of 4 TB each in RAID-6, which is certainly well within the financial reach even of individuals.

The same thing has been done with different editions of Windows, [artificially limiting the amount of usable RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension#Microsoft_Windows) even though the underlying architecture allowed plenty more to be used.

> So are there any caveats in 32 bit systems and large files? I assume that certain 32-bit programs would not be able to load files of more than 4GB or am I wrong?

That depends on the software, and to a lesser extent how it works with its data files, so yes, if the operative words are *certain 32-bit programs* then your assumption is almost certainly correct. Then again, *certain 64-bit programs* might not deal well with huge files either. I run into this occasionally at work; for example, Microsoft Word 2010 will for me refuse to load any file that is larger than 512 MB, even though I have plenty more memory than that available if it were only to try to use it.

*If the software tries to load the entire file into memory at once* (which it really shouldn't) and doesn't have artificial limitations, the limiting factor with current operating systems will be the available virtual memory size. (Note: [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and swap are two completely different things. You also need to consider [memory overcommitting](https://serverfault.com/q/485798/58408).) If on the other hand the software loads only a portion of the file into memory at any one time, as long as the OS itself provides facilities to access portions of the file beyond the 32-bit size boundary of 4 GiB and the file system can deal with the size of the file, the actual size of the file should pretty much not be a concern at all, and if it is, that is likely a userland software bug.

Comment: You formulated it better and more expansive than I did. Nice!

Comment: @Tonny It actually started out as a comment, but then I decided it was better off as a full-fledged answer instead.

Comment: It's better that way. I agree :-)